# Traductions des verbes " enquire ", " enclose " et " keep " pour une lettre de motivation

Tags: traduction, formulation-idiomatique

Je veux traduire la proposition ci-après. La phrase française fera partie d'une lettre de motivation pour une candidature spontanée.

> I am writing to enquire if you have any vacancies in your company. I
>   enclose my CV for your information.

**savoir** et **joindre** peuvent exprimer le sens des verbes **enquire** et **enclose**, respectivement ?

Dans la proposition ci-dessous:

> In case you do not have any suitable openings at the moment, I would
>   be grateful if you would keep my CV on file for any future
>   possibilities.

**conserver** peut-il exprimer ou pas le sens du verbe **keep** dans ce contexte ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- **enquire** : non, "savoir" n'est pas la traduction de "enquire". Si on écrit "je vous écris pour savoir si [...]", on est en train de dire "I am writing to know if [...]". Si on veut vraiment traduire "enquire" littéralement, il faudrait écrire "je vous écris pour vous demander si [...]". Ce n'est pas la même chose même si les sens sont proches. Les deux sont corrects, en tout cas. *(Remarque : on peut également traduire par "s'enquérir de", par exemple, "je vous écris pour m'enquérir des postes vacants dans votre société", mais ça fait vraiment très formel/littéraire. Je ne l'utiliserais pas personnellement.)*
- **enclose** : oui, "joindre" signifie "enclose". La formule consacrée est "veuillez trouver ci-joint [mon CV]". On peut aussi écrire "je vous prie de bien vouloir trouver ci-joint [...]" si on veut vraiment en rajouter une couche. Pas la peine de rajouter "pour votre information".
- **conserver** : oui, on peut l'utiliser pour traduire "keep". "Je vous serais reconnaissant de conserver mon CV pour [...]", ou même "je vous saurais gré de conserver mon CV [...]" pour un style un peu plus soutenu. (Il faut faire un peu attention ici : "je vous saurais" est au conditionnel, si j'avais écrit "je vous saurai" ce serait du futur, et ça donne une tonalité plus impérative, parce qu'on suppose que la personne va le faire sans lui laisser le choix.)

Comment: En tout cas, je ferais relire une lettre de ce genre par quelqu'un dont le français est la langue maternelle ou au moins quelqu'un qui parle très bien français. Il y a un certain nombre de codes à respecter, et ce n'est pas toujours évident...